# Show a bound sequence with a cluster point is indeed convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

I have been wondering for a while now: How do I show that

$(i) \space (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.
$(ii)\space (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and has a cluster point.

essentially are the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) implies ii), but converse is not true - consider $a_n=(-1)^n+1/n$.

---

But, how to prove ii) from i)? I'll give some hint: use the definition of convergence of sequence. From this fact you can prove that every convergent sequence is bounded. Trivially, every convergent sequence has *the* limit point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yes proving $(ii)$ from $(i)$ is pretty trivial. If I change the second statement to "$(ii) \space (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and has exactly one cluster point" though it becomes a little more interesting right?

Comment: @soohyung If $(a_n)$ has only one limit point, then it converges!

Comment: Ah, yes! But how do I actually show that it converges just from knowing that $r \leq a$ for every $r \in R$ with R being the range of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a being the cluster point of the range of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$?  Edit: Can I somehow tell that $r<a$ just from the fact that it's bounded and that a is the only cluster point?

Comment: @soohyung That is, you try to prove that if $a$ is a supremum of the set given by the union of the range of $(a_n)$ and set of the cluster point of $(a_n)$, then $a$ is a limit point of $(a_n)$?

Comment: (Hmmm... I am so confused :( )

Comment: By Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, every bounded sequence has convergent subsequence. So if $(a_n)$ diverges, then it has at least two limit point.

Answer (score 2):

Take the sequence in the plane $(x,sin(1/x)$, any point on $(0,y)$,$0<y<1$ is a cluster point.
To prove ii) from i):
If the sequence converges then the limit is a cluster point, so it has a cluster point.
Similarly if the sequence converges then for any $\epsilon>0$ we have an $N$ such that $|a_n - L|<\epsilon$ for L the limit and $n>N$. If the sequence wasn't bounded we'd have some $N$ such that $|a_n-x|>\epsilon$ for all x, this clearly isn't the case, take x = L.
Therefore i) implies ii)